# align instance rotation to curve rotation/normals

Tags: rigging, geometry-nodes

i am struggling to get the correct rotation of my instances.

I am trying to create an animatable rail road track like this:
[image]

but i don't get these bars underneath the track to align with the curve.

Since those bars are animated the Position on the curve changes and therefore the angle they should be in.
So every Instance has its own rotation depending on the Position of the curve.

This is my current attempt to get the rotation, but it doesn't work:
[image]

Here is the Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19RUohooJowNA_S_Zpx2AY0997LZXskKX/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for your Help in advance. :)